# Class not found or FindClass returns NULL helloWorld

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm trying to run JNI hello world example.

Here is my folder structure:

```
helloWorld.jar
hello_world
helloWorld.class
hello_world.c
helloWorld.java
Makefile
```

**helloWorld.java**

```java
public class helloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

**hello_world.c**

```c
JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM **jvm)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options.optionString = (char*)"-Djava.class.path=/fullpath/hello_world/";
    args.options = &options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
    int rv;
    rv = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &args);
    if (rv < 0 || !env)
        printf("Unable to Launch JVM %d\n",rv);
    else
        printf("Launched JVM! :)\n");
    return env;
}

void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env)
{
    jclass hello_world_class;

    hello_world_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "helloWorld");
    printf("hello_world_class: %x\n",(int)hello_world_class);
}
```

output:

> ./hello_world
> Launched JVM! :)
> hello_world_class: 0

What could be wrong? Why it cannot FindClass?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your java class has no package name so it's using the default package, however you have to give that class a package because you can't find classes at the default package as far as I know so give your java code a package and do:

```
jclass hello_world_class;

hello_world_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "your/package/name/helloWorld");
printf("hello_world_class: %x\n",(int)hello_world_class);
```

Comment: Actually reason of my problem was in different direction. To build jar I used one version of jre from system) but when I run it from C++ I used different version - 1.6 JRE. When I rebuilt my JAR using JRE 1.6 problem was fixed.